# How to retrieve data from memory stored by device controlled with ActiveX in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, camera, activex

I have a USB camera ([DCC1645](http://www.thorlabs.com/NewGroupPage9.cfm?ObjectGroup_Id=4024&popupcart=yes)) which I am trying to interface with through MATLAB. I have successfully connected it to it through ActiveX:

```
cam = actxcontrol('uc480.uc480Ctrl.1');
```

and I can run various functions on it etc. I am now wondering how to retrieve the image data; the relevant function returns a pointer to the image in memory:

```
GetImageMem() returns the pointer to the internal image memory where the image is stored.
```

and so if I run

```
loc = cam.GetImageMem();
```

then `loc` is some big number representing the memory location. The function which gets how much memory is stored is as follows:

```
InquireImageMem(LONG* nWidth, LONG* nHeight, LONG*nBits, LONG* nPitch) 
reads the properties of the allocated image memory. The function returns 
the properties of the actual image buffer, as returned by GetImageMem

nWidth     Receives the width of the allocated image memory.
nHeight    Receives the height of the allocated image memory.
nBits      Receives the bits per pixel of the allocated image memory.
nPitch     Receives the pitch of the allocated image memory. The pitch 
           is the number of bytes from the start of a line to the start 
           of the next line.
```

So my question is two fold:

1. How do you get the actual data given a pointer to the memory and the size?
2. How do you pass a reference to a function (eg LONG* nwidth)? Is there something like libpointer I should use?

Thanks!

Comment: I figured out the answer to part 2:
`[a,b,c,d]=cam.InquireImageMem(0,0,0,0);`

Answer (score 2):

According to IDS, the COM framework is no longer supported, so you should consider switching to the NET framework. I think the post from lunarquaker refers to an older version. Here is a code snippet that if copied and pasted into Matlab should work with no amendments with camera model # UI-1220SE-M-GL (it does for me). You can change the pixel format for coloured cameras.

Tested in Matlab 8.3.0.532 (R2014a), uEyeDotNet Version=1.5.3.0 and IDS/uEye v4.40.0.0

**NOTE** - you must "Exit" before trying to initialize the same camera again otherwise you find yourself in a world of trouble.

```
%   Add NET assembly if it does not exist
%   May need to change specific location of library
asm = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies;
if ~any(arrayfun(@(n) strncmpi(char(asm.Get(n-1).FullName), ...
        'uEyeDotNet', length('uEyeDotNet')), 1:asm.Length))
    NET.addAssembly(...
        'C:\Program Files\IDS\uEye\Develop\DotNet\signed\uEyeDotNet.dll');
end

%   Create camera object handle
cam = uEye.Camera;

%   Open 1st available camera
%   Returns if unsuccessful
if ~strcmp(char(cam.Init), 'SUCCESS')
    error('Could not initialize camera');
end

%   Set colormode to 8-bit RAW
if ~strcmp(char(cam.PixelFormat.Set(uEye.Defines.ColorMode.SensorRaw8)), ...
        'SUCCESS')
    error('Could not set pixel format');
end

%   Set trigger mode to software (single image acquisition)
if ~strcmp(char(cam.Trigger.Set(uEye.Defines.TriggerMode.Software)), 'SUCCESS')
    error('Could not set trigger format');
end

%   Allocate image memory
[ErrChk, img.ID] = cam.Memory.Allocate(true);
if ~strcmp(char(ErrChk), 'SUCCESS')
    error('Could not allocate memory');
end

%   Obtain image information
[ErrChk, img.Width, img.Height, img.Bits, img.Pitch] ...
    = cam.Memory.Inquire(img.ID);
if ~strcmp(char(ErrChk), 'SUCCESS')
    error('Could not get image information');
end

%   Acquire image
if ~strcmp(char(cam.Acquisition.Freeze(true)), 'SUCCESS')
    error('Could not acquire image');
end

%   Extract image
[ErrChk, tmp] = cam.Memory.CopyToArray(img.ID); 
if ~strcmp(char(ErrChk), 'SUCCESS')
    error('Could not obtain image data');
end

%   Reshape image
img.Data = reshape(uint8(tmp), [img.Width, img.Height, img.Bits/8]);

%   Draw image
himg = imshow(img.Data, 'Border', 'tight');

%   Acquire & draw 100 times
for n=1:100
    %   Acquire image
    if ~strcmp(char(cam.Acquisition.Freeze(true)), 'SUCCESS')
        error('Could not acquire image');
    end

    %   Extract image
    [ErrChk, tmp] = cam.Memory.CopyToArray(img.ID); 
    if ~strcmp(char(ErrChk), 'SUCCESS')
        error('Could not obtain image data');
    end

    %   Reshape image
    img.Data = reshape(uint8(tmp), [img.Width, img.Height, img.Bits/8]);

    %   Draw image
    set(himg, 'CData', img.Data);
    drawnow;
end


%   Close camera
if ~strcmp(char(cam.Exit), 'SUCCESS')
    error('Could not close camera');
end
```

Answer (score 1):

1) The short answer is "no", you cannot pull the matrix out of memory in MATLAB even if you know where it is and how big it is. However, this particular camera is supported by the [Image Acquisition toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/imaq/), with a relevant tutorial [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1CBPW/).

The long answer is that if you supplement your MATLAB code with some mex/c, you could make it work, although I don't have any specifics.

2) As I wrote in the comments to the original question,

```
[a,b,c,d] = cam.InquireImageMem(0,0,0,0);
```

will work. Use `cam.methods('-full')` to get a list of all possible methods in the library, and their required inputs/outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the uEye .NET user layer
http://en.ids-imaging.com/manuals/uEye_SDK/EN/uEye_DotNET_Manual/index.html?ueyeinstallation.htm

Below is some example MATLAB code

---

```
clear all

close all

computer_type=computer;

if strcmp (computer_type,'PCWIN64')

NET.addAssembly('C:\Program Files\IDS\uEye\Develop\DotNet\x64\uEyeDotNetUserLayer.dll');

NET.addAssembly('C:\Program Files\IDS\uEye\Develop\DotNet\x64\uEyeDotNetApiLayer.dll');

elseif strcmp (computer_type,'PCWIN')

NET.addAssembly('C:\Program Files\IDS\uEye\Develop\DotNet\x86\uEyeDotNetUserLayer.dll');

NET.addAssembly('C:\Program Files\IDS\uEye\Develop\DotNet\x86\uEyeDotNetApiLayer.dll');

end

cam = uEye.Camera;

cam.Exit();

CAM_ID=2;

exposure_ms=2;

cam.Init(CAM_ID);

ColorMode=uEye.Defines.ColorMode.SENSOR_RAW8;

cam.PixelFormat.Set(11);

cam.Trigger.Set(uEye.Defines.TriggerMode.Software);

[tmp, memId] = cam.Memory.Allocate(true);

[tmp, imgWidth] = cam.Memory.GetWidth(memId);

[tmp, imgHeight] = cam.Memory.GetHeight(memId);

[tmp, imgBpp] = cam.Memory.GetBitsPerPixel(memId);

imgBpp = imgBpp / 8;

imgSize = imgWidth * imgHeight * imgBpp;

bufArr = NET.createArray('System.Byte', imgSize);

soft = uEye.Software(CAM_ID);

soft.SetEnableAutoWhiteBalance(false);

soft.SetEnableAutoGain(false);

soft.SetEnableAutoShutter(false);

cam.Timing.Exposure.Set(exposure_ms); % msec

cam.Acquisition.Freeze(1);

[tmp, camMemPtr] =  cam.Memory.ToIntPtr;

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(camMemPtr, bufArr, 0, imgSize);

img = uint8(bufArr);

myImage=reshape(img, imgWidth, imgHeight)';
```